# How to get the id of the lambda function triggered by api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to get the id of the lambda function triggered by api gateway?

I am getting an unexpected response when I invoke my API, so I would like to look at the logs of the invoked lambda function, for which I need its id.

I went through the docs but couldn't find anything relevant: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can get that information from the `context` object that is passed to the handler callback from AWS.

Check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html. You should be able to use `invokedFunctionArn`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use X-Ray, this could help you debug your Lambda calls and maybe with this you could figure out the solution to your problem.
Take a look at this link and configure the xray in lambda :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-services-lambda.html